# How to convert file content to String in php

Tags: javascript, php

[click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0SoT.png)I'm trying to convert a local php file into string to store it in a Javascript variable.
Is there any way to acheive this?
Here is my php code.

```
<?php 
 $data = get_file_contents("htmlFile.html");
 echo $data;
 >?
```

This data needs to be stored as string in Javascript variable.
I'm facing the below issue:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XVWb.png)

Please give your suggestions to achieve this.

Comment: The string needs to be quoted and escaped properly, or it'll just cause a JS syntax error. Try `echo json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php 
     $data = get_file_contents("htmlFile.html");
?>
```

and use this script

```
<script>
    var jsvar = "<?php echo $data; ?>"
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Irfan. Thanks for your response. :)
I was able to get the file. But the problem is I'm not able to convert it as string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = "<? echo $data; ?>"
```

Remember using `""` characters. That is what is generating erros.